# Magereport is not able to scan Magento website

Tags: magento-1.9, magento1.9.3.7, magereport

When I am trying to scan my website on Magereport.com for security patches, I am getting the following error:

www.xxx.com is returning "**No Magento installation found**"

The website is built upon Magento version 1.9.3.7.

Please guide me, what changes do I need to make to allow Magereport to scan my website.

Comment: make sure you copy the complete url of website  :`http: //xxx.com` from browser and paste in magereport, also you can scan in another tool here : https://magentary.com/magento-security-patch-tester/

Comment: I am using complete URL for the website.

Comment: I have also tried magentary.com tool, but I am getting this message everytime:
Requests are taking a bit longer than expected. Please re-try again clicking on Scan button above in two minutes or so.

Comment: can you please try with complete url of backend once , as like : `http: //xxx.com/admin`.

Comment: Still no luck.. :(

Comment: some others also faced same issue [here](https://community.magento.com/t5/Security-Patches/Are-you-using-Magereport/td-p/52274), this may be `magereport` issue , hope someone will help you here ,otherwise may be [contacting them](https://www.magereport.com/page/contact) is last option

Comment: can you please provide website url i will check

Comment: @BabyinMagento, I have already sent an email to Magereport team, but they have not responded yet.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora thats great buddy, hope you will find solution soon.....

Comment: @RamaChandranM, website URL is https://www.bosterbio.com/.

Comment: i will check @MohitKumarArora

Comment: @MohitKumarArora Hey, when I try to reach that website from here I can't reach it. Are you sure your website is set up correctly? Is there perhaps a firewall which is blocking certain IPs?

Comment: The website is opening in the browser, but magereport.com, magescan.com or magentoversion.com like websites are not able to access it.